# Spark-structured streaming With Kafka

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka

During connecting to kafka topic `imageinstring` with `spark.readStream` I came across this error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o49.load.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:    
org/apache/spark/sql/sources/v2/reader/SupportsScanUnsafeRow
```

I am using:

1. kafka_2.11-0.8.2.2
2. spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7

with following dependencies:

```
org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.4.5
org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.5
```

This is my code :

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
#    Spark
from pyspark.sql import  SparkSession
#    Spark Streaming
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
#    Kafka
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
#    json parsing
import json

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("StructuredNetwork").getOrCreate() 
df=spark.readStream.format("kafka")\
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers","localhost:9092")\
.option("subscribe","imageinstring").load()
query = df.writeStream.outputMode("complete").format("console").start()
query.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: How you added those dependencies to your code ?

Comment: Yes, I ran this on jupyter notebook typing -    pyspark --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.4.5,
org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.5 in cmd.

Comment: And ,I tried with Kafka version - 0.10.0.1

Comment: Can you remove org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.4.5 and try again ??

Comment: I did but didn't work?

Comment: I get the same error in pyspark `2.3.1`, Python `2.7.18` Run spark `spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.3.1`

Comment: It worked when i configured .bashrc  file and added following paths...                'export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::")
export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:jre/bin/java::")
export SPARK_HOME=~/spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.10.8.1-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME/python:$PATH
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=python3'''